# How to I retrieve the IIS Logging, Log Event Destination setting using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis, server, scripting, windows-server-2012-r2

Using PowerShell, I been searching for a command to retrieve which setting radio button option has been selected or the IIS configuration file which stores the      setting.

I been able to retrieve other Logging options but not the above.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Get-Website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/get-website?view=winserver2012-ps) has the information you require:

```
$Site = Get-Website -Name "my web site"
$Site.logfile.directory # log file location
$Site.logfile.logTargetW3C # w3c destinations
$Site.Logfile.logFormat # log format
```

For verifying the destinations, you will need to examine the string value of the `logTargetW3C` property. The values will be `File`, `File,ETW`, or `ETW`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. However, how do I verify that 'Both log file and ETW event'  option has been selected in the IIS Manager Logging GUI?

Comment: @LarryS For verifying the destinations, you will need to examine the string value of the `logTargetW3C` property. The values will be `File`, `File,ETW`, or `ETW`.